# Jsonify nested objects using Jackson

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, jackson

I have a class like:

```
   class Car {
        private Engine engine;
        private String color;  
        private int maxspeed;
    }
```

and Engine class like

```
class Engine {
    private String fueltype;
    private String enginetype;
}
```

I want to convert the Car object to JSON using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) with structure like

```
'car': {
   'color': 'red',
   'maxspeed': '200',
   'fueltype': 'diesel',
   'enginetype': 'four-stroke'
 }
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the [@JsonUnwrapped](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonUnwrapped.html) annotation.

```
class Car {
    @JsonUnwrapped private Engine engine;
    private String color;  
    private int maxspeed;
}
```

For the opposite way, use `@JsonCreator` with `@JsonProperty`.